# How do I add multiple users for keycloak clients

Tags: java, client, single-sign-on, keycloak

I'm trying to make an applications with single sign on with keycloak. I generate realm, clients as per the documentation given by keycloak. But I have to add users for my clients. I have more than 5000 users for each client (application). So I want to know is there any way to add multiple users at a time.
If there is any please guide.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write Java tool that will do the import. Keycloak provides Java libs to work with API. 
Add dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And then you can create a user like this:

```
Keycloak keycloak = Keycloak.getInstance("http://localhost:8080/auth", 
            "master", 
            "admin", 
            "admin", 
            "admin-cli", 
            "password");

UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
user.setUsername("username1");
user.setFirstName("John");
user.setLastName("Doe");
user.setEnabled(true);
Response response = keycloak.realm("master").users().create(user);
```

So it is quite simple and Java tool will give you flexibility to read from different sources types and preprocess/adjust data if needed.